# Why is my project building twice in VS 2015 MSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

So I have a website

Website_RWD
That has three dependencies  SRECLeads, InetLeads, and  BusinessLayer

I am trying to improve the speeds of our builds and deployments.  One thing I stumbled upon was that it seems the main website is building twice.

Poking around on the internet my understanding is that the .metaproj exist because there are project dependencies.

My question is, using TFS Builds or in the solution file is there a way so the project builds in this order.

- BusinessLayer
- SRECLeads
- InetLeads
- Website

As it would build on the local machines.

If the below log is in the correct order you can see that after it builds the website a second time, it builds each individual project.  If that is correct what is the point of doing that and is there a setting to stop that.

[image]

Comment: Are you building multiple configurations? If so, the project could be getting built for each build config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the `Website_RWD` project is not built twice, from what I can see in the log snippet.

The MSBuild log output is structured as tree view, and as you can see the `Website_RWD.csproj.metaproj` is one level above the `Website_RWD.csproj`. That means the `Website_RWD.csproj.metaproj` build somehow contains the `Website_RWD.csproj` build **as a sub-step**.